# PHP - More efficient way to store SQL result in array?

Tags: php

Currently, I have coded this (in PHP).

```
<? $array = array("0");

$q1 =mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `stuff` ORDER BY `id` ASC");

while($q=mysql_fetch_object($q1)){
$array[] = $q->id;
} ?>
```

It doesn't take that long to load, but I was wondering, if there was a more efficient way than this? If there is, please share. It just doesn't feel efficient if there are 1000 rows.

If there isn't, please say so.

Comment: What are trying to do? Do you really need all IDs and "0"?

Comment: **Note**: the mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use PDO or mysqli. PDO for example is offers an API to directly bind a result to an object (or change it according to the result of the query)

Comment: Question solved.

I'll take your advice Rangad. But, if I do, then I will have to convert thousands of lines of code *sigh*, but I guess it will be for the long term benefit.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `mysqli_fetch_all` rather than looping through each row:

```
$q1 ="SELECT id FROM `stuff` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$q1);
$array=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: But this will return a two-dimensional array, each element an array with key `'id'`, while the OP is looking for a straightforward array of the values.